# why am I getting details of all heroes?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want details of specific hero on click of show more.
right now I am getting all hero details on single show more click

```html
 Favourites are as below
    <ul *ngFor ="let item of acts;let i =index;">
      <li>{{item.name}} ``
          <button (click)="getHeroDetails(i)">show More</button>
           <p *ngIf="i == item">{{detail}}</p> 
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <button (click)="clearList()">Remove</button>
```

Comment: post more code related to it

Comment: public getHeroDetails = (hero) =>{
    console.log("hero",this.acts[hero]);
       this.detail = this.acts[hero].power;
  }
this is my Ts code

Comment: yes it was just a try.. i want specific hero details...what ngif condition should i put?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do:

### Script

```
  heroes: any[] = [{name: 'Hero1', power: 'bow'}, {name: 'Hero2', power: 'sword'}];
  expanded: {[i: number]: boolean} = {};

  getHeroDetails(i: number) {
    this.expanded[i] = true;
  }
```

### View

```
<ul *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let i = index">
  <li>
    {{hero.name}}
    <button (click)="getHeroDetails(i)">show More</button>
    <p *ngIf="expanded[i]">{{hero.power}}</p> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptuk9h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Basically, `expanded` maps hero indices to a boolean indicating whether the details are expanded or not for the associated hero. `getHeroDetails` just sets the corresponding flag to true.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have a list of Heroes, and you want to toggle the visibility of their details when the button next to them is clicked.

This can easily be achieved using an Object to keep the track of the Current Object for which the details are to be toggled.

Give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  acts: any[];
  currentlyVisibleHeroData: any = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('assets/heroes.json')
      .subscribe(acts => this.acts = acts);
  }

  toggleHeroVisibility(item) {
    if(this.currentlyVisibleHeroData.visible && this.currentlyVisibleHeroData.id === item.id) {
      this.currentlyVisibleHeroData.visible = !this.currentlyVisibleHeroData.visible;
      this.currentlyVisibleHeroData.id = item.id;
    } else {
      this.currentlyVisibleHeroData.visible = true;
      this.currentlyVisibleHeroData.id = item.id;
    }
  }

}
```

And in the template:

```
Favourites are as below
<ul *ngFor="let item of acts;let i =index;">
  <li>{{item.name}} ``
    <button 
      (click)="toggleHeroVisibility(item)">
      {{ currentlyVisibleHeroData.visible && currentlyVisibleHeroData.id === item.id ? 'Hide': 'Show More'}}
    </button>
    <p 
      *ngIf="item.id == currentlyVisibleHeroData.id && currentlyVisibleHeroData.visible">
      {{item.detail}}
    </p> 
  </li>
</ul>

<button (click)="clearList()">Remove</button>
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tour-of-heroes-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

**NOTE:** I've just added the list of heroes to the `assets/heroes.json` file as you'll be able to see in the Sample StackBlitz. You can use your own implementation in that case. Just make sure to have the Object that keeps track(`currentlyVisibleHeroData` in my example's case)

I'm just toggling the visibility of the item based on whether the item that we're concerned about has the same id as the id in the `currentlyVisibleHeroData` object. The logic is pretty straight forward.